# Javascript/jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem with this Ajax request, it causes error during the call, it is not shown in console nor compiler.

```
Javascript code: 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery.get({
            url: "https://nonsoloalimentatori.it/tools/download-center/index.php?sku="+sku,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: true,
            success: function(){
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("here");
        })


    })
```

PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function searchJson($sku){
    $array = [];
    $json = file_get_contents('./list.json'); //read the file contente
    $json_data = json_decode($json,true); //creating the json objectt
    $n_elementi = count($json_data); //count the number of object element
for ($mul = 0; $mul < $n_elementi; ++$mul){ //for every element it is 
searched the sku
        if($json_data[$mul]["sku"] == $sku)//and it is compared to the sku 
        given by user
        {
            array_push($array,$json_data[$mul]);//if it is true the element 
        is added to array
        }
}
return $array; //it is returned
}

if(isset($_GET['sku'])){
$result=searchJson($_GET['sku']);

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

Comment: Mmm, I would put in a console.log prior to it loading. Could be that your html isn't properly formed and the jquery isn't running. Also do you have jquery installed. Check your jquery version vs your browser version. Some of the jquery versions don't run on the earlier IE browsers.

Comment: Try changing your error code to `error: function(error){console.log(JSON.stringify(error));} `. That way it will actually print out what caused the Ajax to fail

Comment: @MattL. why `JSON.stringify(error)` ?. Simply do  - `error: function(error){console.log(error);}`

Comment: @dhaker The error function packages the error message as a JSON object, so converting it to a string can help condense it to one line in the console

Comment: Personally I like seeing the object be put into console, as it lets me drill into it (might be a Chrome only thing). But either way works, and the stringify is good for those just getting started into using the console for debugging.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes, I also like seeing the object :)

Comment: Luca - You need to debug some more - set a breakpoint in your JS code to check that the AJAX call actually happens. Watch the network tab to see what URL (if any) is actually called by the AJAX request. It strikes me that in your example code `sku` is not defined - have you actually set this variable in reality? Please clarify. If the AJAX call _does_ happen, then check what response, if any, comes back from the server and what the HTTP status code is. If that doesn't reveal much, start doing some server-side debugging etc

Comment: remove dataType, or change it to not jsonp.

Answer (score -1):

On jsonp response from the server side, jquery expects it to be under a callback function.

Please use the following code to output the server response:

```
 $callback_function_name = !empty($_GET['callback'])? $_GET['callback'] : 'callback';
 echo $callback_function_name.'('.json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).')';
```

Reason for the callback function is: cross domain ajax call is not allowed in javascript, so in jsonp the url is loaded the way we load a js script file(you can add script from different domains in your site). The loaded script is then evaluated. If plain data is printed, it does nothing. So it is passed to a callback function registered by the caller JS to process.

You can set your own callback function too by setting:
**jsonp : "custom_callback_function_name"**
inside the ajax function as a parameter.
In that case your server side output should be like:

```
custom_callback_function_name({...json_data...});
```